# Javascript get X parent node without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom, element, nodelist, parent-node

I'm manually scraping data from some websites just using "Javascript:;" in a browser's
address bar. It's easier than copy/pasting.

I've come across a few instances where I have to do: object.parentNode.parentNode....
to get some information and as it varies from site to site it could be at any level.

Obviously I don't want a loop and traverse it as that would make a simple task a bit more
extensive.

Is there a way to do say: object.parentNode[4] or something such as without jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll manage to avoid a good ol' loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<4 && node.parentNode; node=node.parentNode, i++); alert(node);
```

Comment: Alas, I think you're right. Google wasn't much help, thought their may be a none standard method in IE (As it's so compliant :-).

Comment: You can have a look at `document.querySelector()`, maybe you can match the parent directly, without needing to go up parent nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to do exactly this in Vanilla JavaScript:

https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/queryparent

Here's the es5 version:

https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/queryparent/blob/master/index-es5.js

Or if you only need to support modern browsers, you can use the es6 version:

https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/queryparent/blob/master/index.js

You call it like so:

`queryParent(SELECTOR, PARENT);`

It will return the raw JavaScript node.

Here's a demo of it getting the exact class selector you would want, even though there is another element with the same selector (that you would not want):

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/zkw0gdj7/

```js
/*! queryParent.js v1.2.1 by ryanpcmcquen */
/*global module*/
/*jshint esversion:6*/

const d = document;
const qu = 'querySelector';

const queryParent = (s, p) => {
  const q = (x) => d[qu](x);
  const qa = (y) => d[`${qu}All`](y);
  const pa = qa(p);
  (typeof s === 'string') && (s = q(s));
  return [...pa].filter((n) => {
    return (n.contains(s)) ? n : false;
  }).pop();
};

//module.exports = queryParent;

console.log(
  queryParent('.bar', '.foo')
);

// PSST! Check the console!
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="foo">
    But there is also a <code>foo</code> we don't want here.
  </ul>
  <ul class="foo">
    The <code>foo</code> we want is here.
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul class="bar"><code>bar</code> is here.</ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The reason I find this more useful, is that it does not rely on a certain number of `.parent()` calls (or conversely `.parentNode` in pure JS). For that reason it makes your code more future proof and less likely to stop working should the markup structure change.